# Detect call status in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-call, core-telephony

My app is recording audio as a feature, but while a call is connected and I open my app's record button, the app crashes.

I want to show an alert that the record can not work while a call is in progress.

How can I check the call's status on button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/index.html) and check whether its `currentCalls` has more than zero elements in it. You can also use its `callEventHandler` property to proactively disable and reenable the “record” button in your UI.